# Enviar arquivo para site e pegar o caminho do arquivo

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Gostaria de enviar um arquivo para um `input` tipo `file` e recuperar o caminho do arquivo completo. 
Se alguém conhecer alguma coisa parecida será muito útil para mim.

Comment: Qual linguagem você está utilizando?

Comment: PHP ou JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Qual a utilidade disso??? Não vejo nenhum outro a não ser tentar hackear algum site

Comment: Você quer fazer um upload e obter o caminho do arquivo no servidor, ou pegar o caminho na máquina cliente?

Comment: Estou fazendo uma intranet onde as pessoas tem que colocar o caminho do servidor. Para facilitar preciso que a pessoa escolha o arquivo e eu irei guardar o caminho no banco de dados.

Comment: Qual linguagem você utiliza ou vai utilizar?

Comment: Desculpe, mas ainda não está claro. Se você estiver tentando pegar o caminho local do arquivo (antes do upload) via javascript, isso não funciona em alguns browsers, por questões de segurança.

Comment: Para tentar clarificar, o utilizador arrasta um ficheiro para a área de _drag-n-drop_, quando esse ficheiro cai na referida área, pretendes extrair o caminho local do mesmo tipo `c:\bananas\homem.txt` e guardar na base-de-dados, é isso?

Comment: É isso mesmo. Como posso fazer?

Comment: Alguém tem a resposta??

Answer (score 1):

```
$caminhoArquivo = "";
$diretorio = $_POST['nome_diretorio'];

if (file_exists($diretorio)&&is_dir($diretorio )) {
    // mova o upload para esse diretório
    caminhoArquivo = $diretorio."/".$nomeUpload;
} else {
    // como o diretório informado não existe, é preciso criá-lo
    if (mkdir($diretorio , 0777)) {
        // mova o upload para esse diretório
        caminhoArquivo = $diretorio."/".$nomeUpload;
    } else {
        echo "Falha ao criar diretório";
    }
}
```

Comment: Você poderia explicar sua solução?

Comment: Não entendi muito sua explicação.

Comment: -1, pois aparentemente não possui relação com a questão. Reverterei caso ocorra esclarecimento.